# sudo: someсomand: someсomand not found

Tags: linux, ubuntu, sudo, xubuntu

Тут плохо форматируется консольный вывод, так что лучше скрином будет.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Работаю с библиотекой https://fo-000.github.io/bluing/#-usage
Тут дока требует заюзать команду через судо, однако через sudo она не юззается. Когда пытаюсь без sudo заюзать, то, естественно, не хватает прав. Так вот, вопрос, как добавить эту команду в sudo и почему её сразу не видно для sudo? Вообще, болишнство команд у меня без проблем доступны через sudo, а вот эта и ряд других некоторых - тоже нет.

Информация об ОС(я там еще по верх xubuntu накатил себе, но не думаю что это должно как то влиять):

```
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="20.04.5 LTS (Focal Fossa)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS"
VERSION_ID="20.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=focal
UBUNTU_CODENAME=focal
```

Comment: Потому что запуск sudo сбрасывает переменную PATH, а сбрасывает потому, что запускать от имени рута файлы, не принадлежащие руту, — небезопасно и дурной тон

Comment: @andreymal ок, представим что ничего дурного в этом нет и это безопасно. Как мне тогда запустить эту команду через sudo? наверняка есть рецепт в пару строк как внести эту команду для sudo

Comment: Сперва открыть рутовую консоль, а уже потом активировать venv

Comment: @andreymal спасибо, помогло))